# Selenium Implicit/explicit waits doesn't work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using chrome browser. In the "test" method, I set up implicit wait for 60 seconds. I don't see browser waiting for 60 seconds at all. Is there any global setting that has to be done?

I tried explicit wait as well

```
WebDriverWait await = new WebDriverWait(achromeDriver, 60)
```

Implicit wait:

```
aChromeDriver.manage.timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.Minutes)
```

Any suggestions please
I read this article about waits 
https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

Comment: What are you trying to wait FOR? You also said explicit waits don't work, but you haven't provided any example of that. Implicit wait is exactly what it sounds -- if you have an implicit wait, and call `driver.FindElement`, your driver will implicitly wait UP TO 60 seconds for the element to be present, before locating it. So if the element loads immediately, your implicit wait will not wait 60 seconds, because desired condition has already been met. Driver will wait anywhere from 0-60seconds depending on the condition, which is why I ask what you are waiting FOR.

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit or explicit waits means waiting either for the time specified or the page/element to load respectively.

In your case, the browser doesn't wait for 60 seconds if the page/elements are already loaded/present. The browser only waits until the page/elements are shown up or the time given is over, whichever comes first.

If you want the browser to wait for 60 seconds (without considering the state of the page/element), you can use hard waits like `Thread.sleep()`